# Received exception: SSL handshake failed

Tags: codenameone

Am trying to login to my app using codenameone facebook social login api through the emulator but am getting this error message:

> Received exception: SSL handshake failed

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Facebook changed their certificates or that you have a connection issue. Check your JDK and certificate chain.

Comment: the error is coming from WebEngine class of javafx.scene.web; package. And my network connection is OK. How can I check if Facebook changed their certificates?

Comment: It's now working, I changed the redirectURI from https:// to http:// and it worked. But another issue is that in the emulator the LoginCallback class's loginSuccessful() method is never called rather the redirectURI web page loads though works well on the actual device. Is that normal?

Comment: Actual devices use native login, the approach the simulator uses was somewhat deprecated with Facebook offering no real alternative to that approach. It works partially so we can debug but it's not ideal